# which is the cheapest camera with a CCD/CMOS image sensor that can click RAW images?

Tags: raw

I need to click RAW images for an experiment. However my camera does not support that format. The DSLRs have the ability t click RAW format images, but I need the minimum priced camera, with good enough quality.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the experiment is about?

Comment: Here is a list of compact cameras which have RAW capability.   https://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras#criterias=SpecsCoreParams%2CSpecsUncompressedFormatNew&paramSpecsCoreParamsBodyType=Compact%2CUltraCompact%2CLargeSensorCompact%2CSLRLikeCompact&paramSpecsUncompressedFormatNew=RAW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CHDK (Canon Hack Development Kit) adds RAW capabilities to Canon powershot digital cameras, according to the [FAQ](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ):

> It is likely that any Canon Powershot based on the DIGIC II, DIGIC III or DIGIC 4 platforms can be supported

The current list of supported cameras from that same FAQ with the firmware version:

- A410: 100e, 100f
- A420: 100b
- A430: 100b
- A450: 100d
- A460: 100d
- A470: 100e, 101a, 101b, 102c
- A480: 100b
- A490: 100d, 100e, 100f
- A495: 100d, 100e, 100f
- A530: 100a
- A540: 100b
- A550: 100c
- A560: 100a
- A570: 100e, 101a
- A580: 100c, 101b
- A590: 100e, 101b
- A610: 100d, 100e, 100f
- A620: 100f
- A630: 100c
- A640: 100b
- A650: 100d
- A700: 100b
- A710: 100a
- A720: 100c
- A800: 100b, 100c
- A810: 100b, 100d, 100e
- A1000: 100a, 100b
- A1100: 100a, 100b, 100c
- A1200: 100a, 100b, 100c
- A1300: 100b, 100d, 100e
- A1400: 100b
- A2000: 100a, 100b, 100c
- A2100: 100a
- A2200: 100b, 100c, 100d
- A2300: 100c, 100e, 100f
- A2400: 100c, 100d, 100e
- A2500: 100a
- A2600: 100c, 100d
- A3000: 100b, 100c, 100d
- A3100: 100a, 100b, 100d
- A3200: 100a, 100c, 100d
- A3300: 100a, 100c, 100d
- A3400: 100f, 101a, 101b
- A4000: 100c, 101a, 101b, 102a
- D10: 100a, 100b
- D20: 100b
- D30: 100a
- G1X: 100e, 100f, 100g, 101a
- G7: 100e, 100g, 100i, 100j
- G9: 100d, 100f, 100g, 100h, 100i
- G10: 102a, 103b, 104a
- G11: 100f, 100h, 100j, 100k, 100l
- G12: 100c, 100e, 100f, 100g
- G15: 100b, 100e
- IXUS30 (SD200): 100k
- IXUS40 (SD300): 100j, 100k
- IXUS50 (SD400): 101a, 101b
- IXUS55 (SD450): 100b, 100c, 100d
- IXUS60 (SD600): 100a, 100d
- IXUS65 (SD630): 100a
- IXUS70 (SD1000): 100c, 101a, 101b, 102a
- IXUS75 (SD750): 100b, 101a, 101b, 102a
- IXUS80 (SD1100): 100c, 101a, 101b
- IXUS85 (SD770): 100a, 100b
- IXUS90 (SD790): 100c, 100d, 100e
- IXUS95 (SD1200): 100b, 100c
- IXUS100 (SD780): 100b, 100c
- IXUS105 (SD1300): 100b, 100c, 100d
- IXUS110 (SD960): 100b, 101d, 101f, 101g
- IXUS115 (ELPH100HS): 100c, 101a, 101b, 101c
- IXUS120 (SD940): 100e, 101a, 102c, 103b, 103c
- IXUS125 (ELPH110HS): 100d, 100e, 101a
- IXUS130 (SD1400): 100a, 100c
- IXUS132 (ELPH115): 100b
- IXUS135 (ELPH120): 100b
- IXUS140 (ELPH130): 100a, 100b
- IXUS150 (ELPH140): 100c
- IXUS160 (ELPH160): 100a, 100b
- IXUS200 (SD980): 100c, 101c, 101d
- IXUS220 (ELPH300HS): 100c, 101a, 101c, 101d, 101e, 101g
- IXUS230 (ELPH310HS): 100a, 100b, 100e
- IXUS240 (ELPH320HS): 100c, 100d, 101a, 102a
- IXUS255 (ELPH330HS): 100f, 100h
- IXUS300 (SD4000): 100d
- IXUS310 (ELPH500HS): 100a, 101a, 101b, 101c
- IXUS700 (SD500): 101a, 101b
- IXUS750 (SD550): 100f, 100g, 100h
- IXUS800 (SD700): 100b, 101a, 101b
- IXUS850 (SD800): 100d, 100e
- IXUS860 (SD870): 100c
- IXUS870 (SD880): 100e, 101a, 102b
- IXUS900 (SD900): 100c
- IXUS950 (SD850): 100c
- IXUS960 (SD950): 100c, 100d
- IXUS970 (SD890): 100b, 100c, 100d, 100f
- IXUS980 (SD990): 100e, 101b
- IXUS1000 (SD4500): 100b, 100d, 100f, 101a, 102b
- IXUSIZOOM (SD30): 100f, 100g, 100h
- IXUSW (SD430): 110a
- Powershot N: 100a
- Powershot N Facebook: 100a
- S2IS: 100e, 100f, 100g, 100i
- S3IS: 100a
- S5IS: 101a, 101b
- S80: 100g
- S90: 100c, 101a, 101b, 101c
- S95: 100e, 100h, 100i, 100k
- S100: 100d, 100e, 101a, 101b, 102a
- S110: 101b, 102b, 103a
- SX1: 200h, 201a
- SX10: 100c, 101a, 101b, 102b, 103a
- SX20: 100f, 102b, 102c, 102d
- SX30: 100e, 100h, 100l, 100m, 100n, 100p
- SX40HS: 100d, 100f, 100g, 100i
- SX50HS: 100b, 100c
- SX100IS: 100b, 100c
- SX110IS: 100b
- SX120IS: 100b
- SX130IS: 101c, 101d, 101f
- SX150IS: 100a
- SX160IS: 100a
- SX170IS: 100a, 101a
- SX200IS: 100c, 100d
- SX210IS: 100c
- SX220HS: 100a, 101a, 101b, 101c, 101e
- SX230HS: 100c, 101a, 101b, 101c, 101e
- SX240HS: 100a, 100c, 101a
- SX260HS: 100b, 100c, 101a
- SX500IS: 100c, 100d, 100e
- SX510HS: 100a, 100c, 100d, 101a
- SX520HS: 100b, 100c
- SX530HS: 100c
- TX1: 100g, 101b